# Segmentation Fault on calling push_back on a vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a tree structure of objects for simple rows of integers. Here's my testcase:

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::queue;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Node
{
    Node(int r, int i)
      : id(i)
      , row(r)
    {}

    explicit Node(int i)
      : id(i)
      , row(0)
    {}

    Node()
      : id(0)
      , row(0)
    {}

    int nextLayer(queue<int>& queue, int& curRow)
    {
        int nextId = queue.front();
        queue.pop();

        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            if (children[i].id == nextId) {
               if (children[i].row == 0)
                  return children[i].nextLayer(queue, curRow);
               else
                  return children[i].row - 1;
            }
        }

        if (queue.size() == 0) {
            curRow++;
            children.push_back(Node(curRow, nextId));
            return curRow - 1;
        }
        else {
            children.push_back(Node(nextId));
            return children.end()->nextLayer(queue, curRow);
        }
    }

    int id;
    int row;
    vector<Node> children;
};

int main()
{
    queue<int> test;
    int row = 0;
    test.push(1);
    test.push(2);
    test.push(3);

    Node testNode;
    cout << testNode.nextLayer(test, row) << endl;
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/611d8888f7724099))

```
g++ -std=c++03 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In member function 'int Node::nextLayer(std::queue<int>&, int&)':
main.cpp:32:27: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
                           ^
bash: line 8: 15216 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./a.out
```

When I create a queue with some integers and call `nextLayer` on it, it gives me a segmentation fault. Investigating further, it seems that child Nodes have a `vector<Node>` of size larger than 0.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I've testcased your question. Please do this yourself in future. It should have been an early debugging step for you, though in this case you were very close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
return children.end()->nextLayer(queue, curRow);
```

you dereference `end()` and you should not. For non-empty vector the correct line is

```
return children.back().nextLayer(queue, curRow);
```

Comment: This fixes it, but I don't understand why. I thought `end()` just gives me an iterator that I can use to access the last element. Could you explain?

Comment: Also, `return children.rbegin()->nextLayer(queue, curRow)`. `end()` gives you an iterator to one element after the last one. `rbegin()` gives you an iterator to the last element.

Comment: @RobVerheyen: `end()` gives an iterator *after* the last element, so that (for example) you can loop while `it != sequence.end()` to cover the whole sequence.

Comment: @RobVerheyen: `v.begin() and v.end()` produce an _open_ range. That is, the container goes from `v.begin()` inclusive to `v.end()` exclusive. Mike in fact explained that in his answer.

Answer (score 5):

One problem is

```
return children.end()->nextLayer(queue, curRow);
```

`end()` refers to the position after the last element, not to a valid element; you can't dereference that iterator. You presumably want to access the last element:

```
return children.back().nextLayer(queue, curRow);
```